# Build project which depends on bleeding edge packeges for LTS

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I have to build a deb package for Ubuntu LTS. The project is being developed on Debian/SID with most of its top-level dependencies taken from git. Primarily machine learning stuff in C++, no GUI. I'm not a packet maintainer, I'm primarily Windows user, and have no idea how it could be done. AFAIU I have to build these top level libraries in my home dir in separate folder and link the project statically to avoid dependency hell. Am I correct? Are there other guidelines for this?

Comment: do you want to build a (.deb) package, that you could give to others, or do you just want to build the software for yourself, so you can use it on your computer?

Comment: I'd like to build an internal product which is supposed to be installed by ordinary users of our company and work out of the box on Ubuntu LTS installed from scratch.

Comment: Bleeding-edge --and the implied frequent updates-- on *any* Ubuntu release requires either a PPA (or self-hosted repo) for debs, or a snap. Those are the two package options. LTS vs non-LTS does not seem relevant. Is the requirement really specifically a deb?

Comment: Are there any possibilities to embed all top-level deps to a large  self-contained ELF file? AFAIU Linux allows to link libraries statically.

Comment: That seems more the snap direction than deb. See http://snapcraft.io to head that direction.